# Convert .war file generated by windows to be readable by ubuntu 12.0.4?

Tags: binary, tomcat7, ascii, ubuntu-12.04, war

I am transferring .war file from windows to ubuntu server to deploy it in Tomcat7...
If I am directly deploying it, tomcat is throwing exception "Not readable"

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

So I need convert file to readable format, so that tomcat7 reads it and deploys..

Please let me know how to do that... Any softwares or any commands ? appreciate your help

update:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/mycompany.war
    at org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext.setDocBase(WARDirContext.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4894)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5074)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
```

Comment: How did you transfer the file to Ubuntu? If via FTP, did you use the "binary" transfer mode?

Comment: I transfered using filezilla... default settings...

Comment: How long does the transfer of the file take? If more than a short moment or so, the application server may see an incomplete, partial .war file and will try to deploy that. Boom. - Try to transfer to a .war.tmp for example and, when the transfer is done, rename the file to .war on the server.

Comment: it took a while.... but i think error is due to file format..

Comment: War files should be cross-platform. How did you create your war file?

Comment: I created using maven... I resolved the problem by deploying war file in the server using tomcat manager directly (using ftp to transfer war file and deploying it manually on webapps folder created problem) No problem while using tomcat manager to deploy the app

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the file got corrupted during the tranfer.

Make sure you transfer using binary mode.

More info [here.](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/149/)

Comment: I have used binary mode to transfer files but that didnt workout.. still getting same error